# What Happens When You Access a Shared Function From an Instance of an Object

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, class-design

The context of this question is that I am trying to debug performance issues (apart from the obvious ones I already know about and can find).

I inherited a code base (VB.NET) for an ASP.NET app. This is an app that was developed way back in .NET 1.1 days, and was the first .NET app for a lot of the developers who worked on it.

In this code base is a class called DatabaseUtility that contains several Shared Public methods as well as non-Shared Public Functions and Subs for CRUD operations to the database (SQL Server).

It is common in my "BL" that a method creates an instance of the DatabaseUtility which essentially figures out what the connection string should be and opens a connection, as well as giving the developer a handle to the other methods contained within it.

```
Dim utility as New DatabaseUtility()
```

Once I have that, I start to create parameters that I am going to pass to one of the methods in DatabaseUtility (like GetDataSet). There is a Shared method in my DatabaseUtility called CreateParameter which does essentially that. It creates a SqlParameter object so I can add it to a Parameters collection.

Now, the code base is littered with a lot of this:

```
utility.CreateParameter(...)
```

However, because CreateParameter is a Shared method, I am not sure what is going on behind the scenes. I know because it is a Shared member that an instance of the DatabaseUtility is not created when I call it like this:

```
DatabaseUtility.CreateParameter(...)
```

However, because I am calling it from an instance (utility), does that change the behavior at all?

Comment: I've answered your question as asked, but could you elaborate on what exactly you were concerned about - e.g. what suggested that there was a difference between the two calls?

Comment: Accessing a Shared member through an instance variable can make your code more difficult to understand by obscuring the fact that the member is Shared. Furthermore, if such access is part of an expression that performs other actions, such as a Function procedure that returns an instance of the shared member, Visual Basic bypasses the expression and any other actions it would otherwise perform. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6t76186%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: I was concerned that by calling a Shared method from an instance, it was somehow keeping the instance around longer than it needed to be, or opening up additional connections when it shouldn't be. Truth be told, more than anything else, it just annoys me when I see it... LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [VB.NET spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bf32527d-187c-49fa-8c67-9e9105535550&displaylang=en) (my emphasis).

> A shared method **does not operate on a
>   specific instance of a type** and may be
>   invoked directly from a type rather
>   than through a particular instance of
>   a type. It is valid, however, to use
>   an instance to qualify a shared
>   method.

Therefore, no, it does not matter whether you are calling it from an instance or not.

Comment: Thanks, RB. I was pretty sure that was the answer, but I had to ask. I feel like reworking this code to "fix" all of the Shared method calls... *sigh*

Comment: Oh, I would definitely rewrite it. It's considered a bad practice to call a shared member from an instance, and in C# it's not even allowed!